# how can i get to know customer id after successful / failed transaction of pay pal?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com">

  <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

  <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $pro_title;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php require('inc/shipcalc.php');?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

  <!-- success transaction and failed transaction  url -->
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://httpwwwsachinsinghxyz.000webhostapp.com/su-pay.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://httpwwwsachinsinghxyz.000webhostapp.com/fa-pay.php" />

  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
  src="images/paypal.jpg"
  alt="Buy Now">
  <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

This is my paypal transaction form. My transactions are working perfectly. what i want to know is how can i get customer_id or customer_name from  paypal. so, that i can mail invoice details after payapl transaction. should i send customer id variable in form data to paypal. if so how can i get back that id to my website by paypal. suggest me the possible way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it properly from PayPal they don't really have a "Customer Id" more like a transaction Id which is then mainly used when you get another e-mail from a store or alike.

If you for example look into this: https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/ how they sorted it with the transaction id it maybe guides you into the direction.

Also with the way it's usually handled with PayPal payments the E-mail sent afterwards by the store usually contains the transaction id but the name of the customer who filled out the information.

For example
Jon Doe wants to buy in your store, but pays with a different PayPal, e.g his mothers.

So on the email it'll be Jon Does name but the transaction id will refer to the payment made by the mothers PayPal.

Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field with name `custom` and paypal will return the value you pass with it as-is like

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="YOUR customerId VALUE"/>
```

When you process the return values use `custom` to get back the value you passed.